# Numo::NArrayのmeshgrid

Tags: ruby, narray

RubyのNArrayに関する質問です。

NArrayで下のようなグラフを描いて遊んでいるとします。
しかし、NArrayにはNumPyの `meshgrid` に相当する機能がないみたいです。
そこで似たようなことを実現するために、下のようなコードを書きましたが、少し冗長に見えます。

なにかもっと良さそうな書き方を知っていたら教えてください。

```rb
require 'gr/plot'

_x = Numo::DFloat.linspace(-2, 2, 40)
_y = Numo::DFloat.linspace(0, Math::PI, 20)
x = (_x.expand_dims(0) * Numo::DFloat.ones(_y.size, 1)).flatten
y = (_y.expand_dims(1) * Numo::DFloat.ones(1, _x.size)).flatten
z = (Numo::NMath.sin(x) + Numo::NMath.cos(y))

GR.contour(x, y, z)
```

追記：下のようなのも考えました。

```
z = Numo::NMath.sin(_x) + Numo::NMath.cos(_y).expand_dims(0).transpose
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

本質的な差異はありませんが、`meshgrid()` を `Numo::NArray` クラスのクラスメソッドとして定義するのはどうでしょうか。

```
require 'numo/narray'
require 'gr/plot'

class Numo::NArray
  def self.meshgrid(*v)
    raise(ArgumentError, 'Expected at least 2 arrays.') if v.size < 2
    return \
      (v[0].expand_dims(0) * Numo::DFloat.ones(v[1].size, 1)).flatten,
      (v[1].expand_dims(1) * Numo::DFloat.ones(1, v[0].size)).flatten
  end
end

x = Numo::DFloat.linspace(-2, 2, 40)
y = Numo::DFloat.linspace(0, Math::PI, 20)
x, y = Numo::NArray.meshgrid(x, y)
z = Numo::NMath.sin(x) + Numo::NMath.cos(y)

GR.contour(x, y, z)
```